# External GET Request in Kohana 3.2 is stripped out via factory method

Tags: php, kohana-3.2

I am trying to make an external request. I am following examples provided [here in Kohana Docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/requests#external-requests).

Thing is, I am trying to do a GET with GET params. As soon as I provide a URL with GET params to the factory method, the params get stripped from the URL and placed in `_get` property of the Request object.

Here's how it looks on my side:

```
$request = Request::factory('http://www.example.com/api.php?param1=value1&param2=value2');
$response = $request->execute();
```

If I `print_r` the `$request` object I can see this (extract):

```
[_get:protected] => Array
    (
        [param1] => value1
        [param2] => value2
    )
```

But unfortunately it doesn't looks as if these get sent when executing the request.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`query()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#query) method to set GET data.

```
$request = Request::factory('http://www.example.com/api.php')->query(array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'));
$response = $request->execute();
```